# How does a shadow clone identify itself as shadow clone?

Tags: naruto

All shadow clones have the same memories as the original (from birth until the Jutsu cast time). Which means all the shadow clones also should think of themselves as the original.

If an action needs to be done by only the original, all the shadow clones also would try to do the same. Because they all think that they are the original.

Is it valid? Do shadow clones know that they are just clones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the beginning of the series, Naruto's Shadow Clones did confuse and fight amongst themselves about who's the original one (before realising that all they had to do was to release the jutsu to figure it out).

I'm guessing that as you get more proficient in the technique, both you and the clones begin to recognize who they are.

> In Naruto's most recent case, the original has Gudoudama behind him, while the clones do not.

Answer (score 3):

More experienced ninja have shown to have an increased spacial awareness as well as combat awareness. You can see this in various fights throughout the series.

> In the first fight with Uchiha Itachi, Kakashi showed that he was able to create a water clone in a split second designed to take potentially lethal damage.

Throughout the series, clones are used as decoys just as much as they are used to mitigate damage done to the user. Obviously the user in these cases know *exactly* who is the clone and who is the user.

It would make sense then, that young and inexperienced Naruto with a new clone technique (which isn't that much different than other cloning techniques) would not have the experience or spacial awareness to perceive the differences. However a Naruto that has used the technique hundreds if not thousands of times, as well as having participated in numerous fights, would be able to tell right away.

Now exactly *how* he can tell is mostly speculation, but there are several key points:

- when making the clones, he can choose where the clones appear.

  - One could notice that they were not where they used to be prior to the technique.
  - One could also notice that they have "appeared" as a specific piece within a specific strategy.
- The consciousness of the clones would see an immediate shift (a pop?) from where he was to where they appear.

  - This could also be extended to immediately recognizing one's self as a clone based on "feeling" the shift from using the technique to the clone appearing.
  - One could speculate that the user might even "feel" a shift in the molded chakra from when the user is performing the technique to when the clone appears.

Answer (score 0):

The Clones created doesn't have all the behaviour in self.
In case 3 clones are created one shows depressed mood, second Hyperactive, third one in a Happy mood.
Thus, Original will have every behavior making him recognize himself.
**(naruto shippunden around 250th o something has this concept of shadow clones taking over naruto, more clearly explained there).**

Comment: That episode was about Naruto dreaming correct?

Comment: Yeah, It was about naruto dreaming

Comment: That was a filler, dude.